# Received fatal alert: protocol version for java 1.8 with maven 3.3.9

Tags: java, maven

I upgraded from java 7 to java 8 based on one of the stackoverflow resolved question. My project is now using 1.8 but despite of that I get this protocol version error. I am using maven 3.3.9. I delete the folders in my local repo and give update project. The dependency folders get created. However there are no jars inside. My settings.xml contains the following:

```
<mirror>
      <id>central-secure</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: Are you within a corporate environment ? If not remove that from your `settings.xml` cause by default you don't need. Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade most recent version Maven 3.6.3.

Comment: @khmarbaise No. This is a home laptop. Thanks for that tip on settings.xml. I found that my eclipse.ini file had the -vm argument pointing to javaw.exe in  java 1.7. I changed this to 1.8. Also, -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion was 1.6. I changed that to 1.8. I am able to successfully update my maven project. Though I wonder hows the fix related to maven or the java build path specified for my project.

Comment: How does your pom file look like?